# Experimental APIs settings on multiple Chromebook

Tags: google-chrome, chromebook

User needs to go to chrome://flags/#overlay-strategies in chrome browser and change Select HW overlay strategies from Default to Unoccluded buffers (single-fullscreen, single-on-top). After the change, the user needs to restart the browser. How can I do this on more than 1000 Chromebooks?

Comment: Is there any software that you are currently using to manage these chromebooks?

Comment: No, I thought Google Admin console is the one but I don't see any documentation on that nor I can find the settings on that.